# getting token type in Antlr listener

Tags: c#, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 with C# Target. There is a simple lexer rule in my grammar as follows

```
SearchIdentifier : QTE (WILDCARD | Identifier) QTE  
           | (Digit)+                               
           ;
```

I use this rule in one of the parser rules as follows

```
conditionExpr: Identifier LT SearchIdentifier
```

in my listener, i will like to know which lexer subrule was parsed. For example currently the only thing i get is

```
 context.SearchIdentifier().GetText();
```

this will give me the SearchIdentifier text, is there a way to know which subrule (QT Identifier QT or Digit) was matched ?

Thanks

Comment: how did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ANTLR 4 lexers are state machines that do not track *any* information aside from where the token stops (so it can execute the correct action and assign the correct token type).

This is very different from ANTLR 3 lexers, but also *tremendously* faster.

Comment: How to get the token type while parsing? any other idea, can we get it using visitors?